# SQL conditional group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given this table

```
id_order|id_status|
--------|---------|
141     |4        |
141     |4        |
142     |4        |
142     |4        |
143     |5        |
143     |4        |
```

I want to execute a query that extracts those id_orders that have all id_status equal 4, so in this case, the output should be:

```
id_order
--------
141
142
```

Order with id_order 143 would be excluded due to it has one row with id_status <> 4.

Comment: Note that you appear to have no PRIMARY KEY. This is likely to prove highly problematic in the very near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work, but, depending on your indexes, could be slow

select distinct id_order from t
where id_order not in (select id_order from t where id_status <> 4);

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is nice and easy. I didn't point in that direction at all!

Answer (score 4):

I would just use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id_order
from t
group by id_order
having min(id_status) = max(id_status) and min(id_status) = 4;
```

Comment: I've tried your query and it works fine but please correct me if I am wrong, Does it works because having clause is performed before group by? Is it always like this? BTW, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @cape . . . The `having` clause is *always* performed after the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

Select id_order from t where id_status = 4 group by id_order

Comment: That was my first idea, but in that case, you aren't considering that **all** statuses for an order are 4. Order with id 143 would match your query, what is wrong.